# Displaying a message after successful login

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5

My extension is running as a **backend authentication service**. For some cases I need to display a message to the user after a successful login. I've tried to do this using FlashMessages:

```
$message = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_FlashMessage', 'Title', 'Text', t3lib_FlashMessage::NOTICE, TRUE);
t3lib_FlashMessageQueue::addMessage($message);
```

But to no avail. I guess that is doesn't work because there is no backend user session yet, the message could be stored in.

Is there a way to display a message to the user after a **successful** backend login?

Answer (score 1):

Make a small backend extension and work with Ext.js/ExtDirecty you can easely display some kind of "lightbox" message.. 
Sample:
http://wiki.typo3.org/ExtDirect

gl.

Comment: Thanks. I've never worked with Ext.js but I'll have a look, how this could work.

Comment: I've successfully used Ext.js/ExtDirect to get all FlashMessages to my javascript function and display them as FlashMessages – but the FlashMessages created during the login are not in the FlashMessage queue, so I still can't show the user any messages…

Answer (score 0):

Well, the flashmessages need to be rendered somewhere. You could display them in a backend module for example. Have a look at a standard view template. On default there is a flashmessages viewhelper when your extension was created with the extension builder.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the extension has no backend module because, except for this message, it has nothing to say -- and even if I had a backend module: the users probably wouldn't look at it.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. You could direct to your backend module initially, but as you said, that would be a little to much for one message. So you don't have any space to render flash messages as you do not have a view. You could have a look at the system extensions how they render the popup messages at the top. I don't know if thats possible with a normal extension. Never tried that.